# Netcore: Patron Repositorio y multiples cambios en la base de datos

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, patrones-de-diseño

desde hace poco que estoy desarrollando con netcore y aún hay temas que no entiendo del todo. 
En el siguiente código tengo un controlador al que por Inyección de Dependencias le paso un repositorio.

En el repositorio hago una serie de acciones (entre ellas llamar a otro repositorio).

```
public class AppController : ControllerBase
{
    public virtual async Task<IActionResult> Put(int id, TEntity data)
    {
        //AppRepo
        await repository.Update(data);
        return NoContent();
    }

}

public class AppRepo<App, DataContext> {
    private DataContex _ctx ;

    public async Task<App> Add(App entity)
    {
        await _ctx.Apps.AddAsync(entity);   
        await _ctx.SaveChangesAsync()     
        return entity;
    }

    public async Task<App> Update(App data){
        _ctx.Entry(data).State = EntityState.Modified;
        App newData = await Add(data);
        var dependiente = new AppDependenciasRepo(_ctx);
        await dependiente.updateChangesApp(data.Id, data.Dependencias);
        await _ctx.SaveChangesAsync()
    }
}

public class AppDependenciasRepo<Dependencia, DataContext>
{
   public async Task updateChangesApp(int ApplicationId, List<Dependencia> nuevos){
        Dependencias old = new Dependencias () { ApplicationId = ApplicationId };
        _ctx.Dependencias.Attach(old);
        _ctx.Dependencias.Remove(old);
        await _ctx.Dependencias.AddRangeAsync(nuevos);
        await _ctx.SaveChangesAsync()
   }
}
```

He puesto en cada método de los repositoris _ctx.SaveChangesAsync(), para cuando se hagan llamado independiente se escriban los datos en la db.

Pero cuando hago operaciones mas complejas comienzan las dudas:

```
_ctx.Entry(data).State = EntityState.Modified;
App newData = await Add(data);
```

En las sentencias anteriores quiero modificará el estado y luego agrego un nuevo dato, entiendo que cuando termine Add(data), también se escribirá el nuevo estado de la entidad; por lo que el contexto _ctx, ya no tendrá cambios pendientes.

En el método Update de AppRepo, llamo a updateChangesApp, este primero borra datos para luego ingresar datos substitutos. Como estoy utilizando Async tengo el temor de que primero agregue los datos y luego los borre todos.

```
_ctx.Dependencias.Remove(old);
await _ctx.Dependencias.AddRangeAsync(nuevos);
await _ctx.SaveChangesAsync()
```

¿Son correctos mis suposiciones, es así como se debe trabajar o tal vez debería crear una Unidad de Trabajo para encapsular el llamado a SaveChangesAsync?.

Comment: Hola, @jorge. Cada repositorio es una *unit of work* independiente. No puedes darle la responsabilidad de hacer un `SaveChanges` al *repository* porque no es su trabajo. Y tampoco lo es del controlador, que no debería decidir cuándo guardar datos. El controlador sólo debería mantener la comunicación con terceros (control de errores, *mapping* de datos, ...).

Comment: Te falta una tercera capa en tu sistema que es la encargada de toda la lógica de negocio, **los servicios**. En los servicios se inyectan los repositorios a los recursos  necesarios (sólo a aquellos los cuales cada servicio debería tener acceso) y hacen uso de las *unit of work*. Piensa en el caso de querer añadir un set de datos uno a uno de forma transaccional (no vale el `AddRange`). Si en algún punto del *loop* quiero parar, puedo, y cancelo toda la transacción. Si para cada `Add` se llamada a un `Save`, no podría.

Comment: Sin hablar de *performance*, porque cada `Add` implicaría un viaje a la base de datos. Si agrupas varias *unit of work* te permites el lujo de volcar varios cambios en el contexto virtual de EF de una sola llamada a la base de datos. Las últimas líneas de código son claramente un ejemplo de cómo se vería un método de un **servicio**,  no de un *repository*. Eso es lógica de negocio, no lógica de la capa de acceso a datos.

Comment: Déjame ver si entendí. Debería crear servicios, que son aquellos que se encargarán de la lógica de negocio, el servicio es el encargado de llamar a los repositorios que necesite y es en el servicio donde debería hacer el SaveChanges?
¿Entonces lo que inyecto a los controladores serían servicios?

Comment: Exactamente, @Jorge.

Answer (score 0):

Mi sugerencia es que no utilices el patron repositorio sobre Entity Framework por que estas haciendo una abstraccion sobre otra abstraccion.
Visualiza a tu controlador si en lugar de inyectar el repositorio inyectas la clase DbContext.
Si implementas este mecanismo de inyectar el DbContex en tu controlador tendras acceso a todas las tablas de tu base de datos y las consultas como las modificaciones en BD se verán enormemente simplificadas.
Hacer esto es algo totalmente valido y no rompes niguna regla de arqutiectura, sigues conservando las reglas de Patron repositorio y Unidad de trabajo (por que EF actua como un repositorio y unidad de trabajo), mantienes el codig limpio y mantenible.

Comment: Inyectar el `DbContext` directamente en el *controller* es el mayor antipatrón que puedas hacer. Cada controlador debe tener únicamente acceso a aquello que necesite, para eso son los repositorios. Los repositorios también permiten agregar una capa de abstracción NECESARIA (y no extra, como tú dices). Precisamente es necesaria porque tu sistema debe ser agnóstico a qué ORM usa, a qué proveedor de base de datos necesite e inclusive si es que hay base de datos.

Comment: Tu sistema puede escalar, cambiar de ORM, de proveedor, o trabajar con datos en memoria. La capa del repositorio abstrae todos esos detalles a los demás componentes del sistema. Des de fuera sólo interesa "Oye, dame X cosa", da igual cómo.
De hecho, es tan sencillo de entender con una pregunta. Si vas inyectando por ahí el `DbContext`, ¿cómo vas a hacer *testing* de tu sistema? El testing en EF se consigue precisamente con el *mocking* del *repository*.

Comment: No veo en que sentido es un antipatron, EF como ORM actua de la misma manera que un Repositorio, además, otra cartacteristica de EF es abstraer la base de datos y lograr ser agnostico al proveedor de base de datos que necesites. La idea de que cada controller acceda solo a lo que necesite se logra de la misma manera tanto con EF como con un repositorio encima de EF es ahi donde no le veo la utilidad de meter mas complejidad a tu código

Comment: Por la cuestion de Mocking es facil lograrlo si programas contra interfaces, si abstraes la clase DBContext puedes hacer un mocking simplificado, si estas utilizando EF Core puedes utilizar InMemoryDataBase para lograrlo

Comment: Plantéate qué pasaría si a día de mañana quisieras dejar de usar *Entity Framework*. Como veo que no voy a poder sacar mucho más de ti, sólo te recomiendo que empieces por leer conceptos tan básicos como [SOLID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID). Que vaya bien.

Comment: Si entiendo tu punto totalmente, pero para ser honestos no vas a cambiar de ORM asi como no cambiaremos de manejador de base de datos, pero para resolver la pregunta lo que buscamos es simplificar el desarrollo y ayudar a resolver el problema

Comment: Yo por lo general evito tener lógica del negocio en el controlador y eso incluye consultas/cambios a la base de datos. Si todo lo hago independiente del controlador podría usar el repositorio (luego de lo que dijo @VRoxa, sería servicio) en otra implementación, otro sistema o algo totalmente ajeno a ASP